# Issue with member variable of an activity when using back button

Tags: android, android-activity, member

I've got an activity that shows some item from a list.

When swiping from right to left the same activity is started with the next product and when swiping from left to right I start the same activity with the previous product.

I get the product position from a global array using a member variable `position` that I decrement when going to previous product and increment when going to next product, and that I pass as an extra in the intent.

The issue is that when pressing the back button, the `position` value remains the same as that in the activity where I'm coming from. I understand that onResume is called instead of onCreate and that no extra is passed, but `position` is not static and I expect it to keep its value in the activity instance. Why is this not the case?

Thanks

```
public class ProductHome extends Activity{  

    private int position;
    private Product product;

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_home);

        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("Position", -1);

        product = GlobalData.map_products.get(product_id);

        // swipe detector
        // left -> right: position++
        // right -> left: position--
        // then starts same activity again

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SRPGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        RelativeLayout product_home = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.product_home);
        product_home.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the mode you launch your activity in. Most likely, there is only one instance of your activity.

You probably should not launch a new activity when slinging to the right, and probably not use the back button to go back to the previous product, but rather to the list where you probably com from

Comment: There is already a listview to choose the product. I added the swipe right and left to navigate in that list directly from the item activity. The back button is not used for the navigation, but the user might press it and get this issue.

Comment: like i said, the easier way is to not restart an activity, but rather to update the data with a new value of position. The expected behavior for back is to bring you /back/ hierarchically, that is to the list.

Comment: You're right, that would be better to go back to the list. I could just update the data within starting the same activity again, but I also want an animation, eg same as default activity transition when going to next product and in the other direction when going to previous one. How can I do it within the same activity?

Comment: you could use a view flipper, add a view, animate to the new view, remove the previous one. (i haven't done anything like it, but i suppose that would be a way to do it)