# Switching item from a list within the item activity, with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I've got a list with some items.

On some "item detail" activity I'd like to be able to switch item on swipe (left for previous item, right for next item), with the same animation as the default activity transition (reversed when going to previous item).

I tried it with swipe detection, calling the item activity again with the position of the item in the list and calling `overridePendingTransition` to set the animation when going to previous item, but this is inelegant and I had [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913093/issue-with-member-variable-of-an-activity-when-using-back-button).

How can I achieve this while staying in the same instance of the activity (i.e. not starting the activity again)? On swipe I could just load the new data, but I don't know how I can get the animation.

Any help welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use ViewFlipper ?
And read this article http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/04/viewflipper-with-animation.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the android ViewPager for this. To use it you need to include the compatability library with the application. It allows to swipe between views.

[This is an example for it.](http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html)

Comment: This look very useful, but I need to reload my item every time from a web service (some data might have changed), so in that case a ViewFlipper might be a better option. Thanks for the pointer anyway, I'll sure use this soon.